# Ajax Request returns undefined result

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajax-request

i have a problem with Ajax Request ( Basic function )

**here's ajax function**

```
function ajax(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}
```

**here is another function**

```
 _2xm.load = function (p, type)
    {
      p = p.replace("frame_", "");
      loading(type);
      var req=new ajax();
      var __page =encodeURIComponent(p);
      req.open("GET", "page.php?page="+__page, true);
      req.send(null);
      req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (req.readyState==4)
        {
          if (req.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)
          {
           loading(2);
           return req.responseText;
          }
          else
          {
            loading(2);
            return "An error was occured.... ";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

here is part of code which uses `_2xm.load()` function :

```
_2xm.loadData = [_2xm.load(pg, 0), _2xm.now(), _2xm.interval * 60];
```

but the result is allways `Undefined`, why?

Comment: I like how your `ajax()` carefully considers error cases and returns `false` when an `XmlHttpRequest` object couldn't be created... and then your `_2xm.load` **completely ignores that**.

Answer (score 0):

You never returned a value from `_2xm.load`, so the function implicitly evaluates to `undefined`.

You return values only from the anonymous function callback bound to `req.onreadystatechange`, which fires at some later stage, asynchronously, long after your function call to `_2xm.load` has finished.

Perhaps you should consider a synchronous request.

Comment: Thanks, but how to make a function to send a request, which will be a " synchronous request "

Comment: @John: Whatever documentation you're using for `XMLHttpRequest`, find the part in it that talks about synchronous requests.